# How to migrate from XslTransform to XslCompiledTransform

Tags: xml, vb.net, xmldocument, xslcompiledtransform

I have the following code that I need to migrate from VS 2003 (.Net 1.1) to VS 2008 (.Net 2+)
but I get compilation error -

System.Xml.Xsl.XslTransform' is obsolete: This class has been deprecated. 
I probably need to use System.Xml.Xsl.XslCompiledTransform instead.
but I do not find the matching Load() and Transform() overload versions that I can use with all the parameters of my original code.

in MSDN [How to: Migrate Your XslTransform Code] I only found some simpler cases.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa983475%28VS.80%29.aspx
but in my code I see some remarks that hints that the added parameters were used to avoid exceptions, so I prefer to use these parameters.

Can someone please help migrating this code?

Thanks,
Atara

```
' ----------------------------------------------------------------------   
' VS 2003 code:
' ----------------------------------------------------------------------

. . .

Dim myXslDoc As Xml.XmlDocument

' ----------------------------------------------------------------------   
  Public Sub mcSetParameters(ByVal srcFileName As String)
' ----------------------------------------------------------------------

 Me.myXslDoc = New Xml.XmlDocument 
 Me.myXslDoc.Load(srcFileName) 

End Sub


' ----------------------------------------------------------------------    
  Public Sub mcSetHtml()
' ----------------------------------------------------------------------

 Dim oXPathNav As System.Xml.XPath.XPathNavigator = xmlDoc.DocumentElement.CreateNavigator()

 Dim sbContent As New System.Text.StringBuilder
 Dim swContent As New System.IO.StringWriter(sbContent)        

 Dim args As New System.Xml.Xsl.XsltArgumentList
 args.AddParam("paramName1", "", paramVal1.ToString)
 args.AddParam("paramName2", "", paramVal2.ToString)

 Try
   ' Try to avoid "Invalid site" exception, by using XmlUrlResolver and Evidence.
   ' If the XSLT stylesheet . . . comes from a code base that you trust, Then use Me.GetType().Assembly.Evidence() 
   Dim resolver As System.Xml.XmlUrlResolver = New System.Xml.XmlUrlResolver
   resolver.Credentials = System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials
   Dim xslt As System.Xml.Xsl.XslTransform = New System.Xml.Xsl.XslTransform 
   xslt.Load(Me.myXslDoc, resolver, Me.GetType().Assembly.Evidence())        
   xslt.Transform(oXPathNav, args, swContent, Nothing)                       
 Catch ex As Exception
   Debug.WriteLine("Exception: {0}", ex.ToString())
 End Try

 DoSomething(sbContent.ToString())

End Sub

' ----------------------------------------------------------------------
```

in my old code I have both xmlDoc and xslDoc, so the compiled code I have now (not tested yet) is:

' ----------------------------------------------------------------------
' VS 2008 trial code:

' ----------------------------------------------------------------------

```
  Dim sbContent As System.Text.StringBuilder = New System.Text.StringBuilder()
  Dim swContent As System.IO.StringWriter = New System.IO.StringWriter(sbContent)
  Dim contentWriter As System.Xml.XmlWriter = System.Xml.XmlWriter.Create(swContent)

  Dim args As New System.Xml.Xsl.XsltArgumentList()
  args.AddParam("paramName1", "", paramVal1.ToString)
  args.AddParam("paramName2", "", paramVal2.ToString)

  Try
    Dim resolver As New System.Xml.XmlUrlResolver
    resolver.Credentials = System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials

    Dim evidence As System.Security.Policy.Evidence = Me.GetType().Assembly.Evidence
    Dim secureResolver As New System.Xml.XmlSecureResolver(resolver, evidence)
    Dim settings As New System.Xml.Xsl.XsltSettings(False, True)

    Dim xslt As New System.Xml.Xsl.XslCompiledTransform()  
    xslt.Load(Me.myXslDoc, settings, secureResolver)    
    xslt.Transform(xmlDoc, args, contentWriter)  
  Catch ex As Exception
    Debug.WriteLine("Exception: {0}", ex.ToString())
  End Try

  DoSomething(sbContent.ToString())
```

Answer (score 2):

Those extra parameters are no longer exposed directly by the `XsltCompiledTransform` class. You can now load the transform using any `XmlReader` that you like.

If you need the extra security, then create an `XmlReader` that uses an `XmlSecureResolver`:

```
Private MyXslDoc As String = "XslFilePath"
Public Sub LoadTransform(ByVal paramVal1 As Object, ByVal paramVal2 As Object)
    Dim args As New System.Xml.Xsl.XsltArgumentList
    args.AddParam("paramName1", "", paramVal1.ToString)
    args.AddParam("paramName2", "", paramVal2.ToString)

    Dim resolver As New System.Xml.XmlUrlResolver
    resolver.Credentials = System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials
    Dim evidence As Evidence = Me.GetType().Assembly.Evidence
    Dim secureResolver As New XmlSecureResolver(resolver, evidence)
    Dim settings As New XmlReaderSettings
    settings.XmlResolver = secureResolver

    Dim xslt As New System.Xml.Xsl.XslCompiledTransform()
    Using transformReader As XmlReader = XmlReader.Create(Me.MyXslDoc, settings)
        xslt.Load(transformReader)
    End Using

    Using documentReader As XmlReader = XmlReader.Create(documentUri)
        Dim sbContent As New System.Text.StringBuilder
        Using swContent As New System.IO.StringWriter(sbContent)

            Using contentWriter As XmlWriter = XmlWriter.Create(swContent)
                xslt.Transform(documentReader, args, contentWriter, Nothing)
            End Using
        End Using
    End Using
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks. 
and how do I use the XmlDocument in any xslt.Load() overload?

Comment: Thanks, It will take me a few days to verify that it works as expected. (I need to migrate a large project, meanwhile I still try to avoid compilation errors :(  )